# Jira, Tomcat and JBoss behind Apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, tomcat, jira, jboss

I need to install these environment in the same machine.

**Jira : ( installer, port: 8080, tomcat-jira)

Tomcat : ( tomcat for other applications, port: 8084 )

JBoss : ( port: 8086 )

Apache2: (as a proxy, mod_proxy, port: 80)**

First I´d install Jira as a service, with their installer, so, It came with a tomcat embed, port 8080.

Then I installed apache as a proxy, It worked, I can now acces the jira like this: debian.local/jira intead of debian.local:8080.

But when I put tomcat in the same server the problems began:
I changed the tomcat ports on connectors and shutdown, but when I start it, the Tomcat from Jira goes down, both-ways.

- The question is, how "un-recommended" is to install jira as a WAR deployed on my tomcat, intead of tomcat-jira?
- What´s the best way to configure this environment? How must to be declared the CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE for this?

That´s all... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the JIRA install basically consists of a Tomcat installation + a deployed jira war, why not simply reuse that Tomcat instance? From your description, you would end up with 3 containers - jira-tomcat, tomcat, and jboss.  What is the use case for all 3?

Comment: The advantage to split the installations in sepparated containers is to isolate it, avoiding future problems. If one of the services go down, the other keep running. It´s a good advantage.

Comment: can you upload the server.xml for both the jira and other/base tomcat installations, as well as their respective startup parameters?  Also, is this windows or linux?